# Showing dynamic web-content from iOS local server (i.e. using browser as remote screen)

Tags: iphone, ios, http, webserver, remote-access

I want to show some really simple graphics in a http-page in the local network using an iOS App as local server.
Now I heard showing some http-page over the local network is quite easy, using for example [CocoaHTTPServer](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer).

Would it also be possible to adjust the content of the page dynamically, from the iPhone side?

Meaning

1. user types in URL at the desktop-pc-browser of his choice
2. user goes to his sofa, flicking through text/images with his iPhone, looking at the remote screen
3. (no need to go to the browser to refresh page?)

Would this be feasible?

Of course I could also try to set up some Bluetooth-Connection, connecting between iOS/MacOS Apps, but I figured the browser version would be much more flexible :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stable connection? No need to support each and every browser? Then open up a websocket connection between your app and your browser. You’d then advise your browser to reload or show another picture through the websocket.

If you need to support more browsers, you might need comet / long-polling support. I’m not sure, though, whether CocoaHTTPServer supports it.

If none of these work, you could have your webapp do an Ajax request every now and then, in order to check whether something has changed.

Comment: CocoaHTTPServer supports Websockets, even found a sample project: http://deusty.blogspot.de/2010/04/adding-websockets-to-cocoahttpserver.html
If it works for the recent Safari and Firefox it's ok, I can also tell the user about this, when I ask them to open their browser and type the ip-address of the phone.